# Simple Delete in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Anyone who create a simple delete in codeigniter. help me!**.
this is my view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/del/<?php echo $row->id; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Help me to create a simple delete data in codeigniter .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this
Controller

```
Class Home Extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //blah blah
    }

    function del()
    {
        $id =   $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->mymodel->delete($id);
        redirect('home/index');
    }
}
```

Model

```
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('tablename');
    }
}
```

Comment: sir are you busy? if not. can you create me a simple search? please. please

Comment: Please post a question what you want than i will be able to do something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374188/search-data-in-codeigniter#comment19990301_14374188

Comment: question all ready set :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22889/discussion-between-raheel-shan-and-naksuriya)