# Search Data in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can you help to create a simple search in Codeigniter. i don`t know how. please.

this is my database name tbl_dash

```
tbl_dash

id  |   name    |   Note
_________________________
1   |   erwin   |   Baker
2   |   flores  |   Coke
```

please help me!:(

Comment: what do you want to search and what have you tried so far? Give us more information

Comment: Sample i want to search my name erwin then it show the information about erwin. it is a simple search.

Comment: It seems you haven't tried anything. So i can share the steps alone to do it. You try your own. If you face any difficulty or any error, then get back here. Find the steps in the answer section

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.
View

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('search/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
<input type="text" name = "keyword" />
<input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
Class Search Extends CI_Contrller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }

}
```

Model

```
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('name',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('tablename');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

EDITS :
Here is the view to display data. result_view.php

```
<table>
<?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->Company?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->Source?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->SavePitch?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->Results?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->Status?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->user_id?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: just wonder if 2.1 need to  `call parent::__construct()` each time

Comment: what do you mean? please explain.

Comment: the output. how to build into a table ?

Comment: I like this example but how would i go about not showing all the records but just the record that was searched only

Comment: the query uses `like` phrase if you want exactly match the use `where` instead

Answer (score 0):

Steps to achieve this:

1) Create a view which should contain search form with text field name and submit button.

2) Validate the field and post the value into a controller.

3) Get the posted value in controller and try to validate in server side.

4) Pass the value to a model.

5) In model, generate a select query which should fetch the required information according to the search input and return the fetched values to controller.

6) From controller pass the results to whatever the view you want.

7) Display the results in view page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [active record class docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html),

```
$this->db->where('name','erwin');
$result=$this->db->get('tbl_dash');
$this->load->library('table');
//HTML table in $table now;
$table=$this->table->generate($result);
```

Comment: correct your instruction. last line