# cant fetch row data from database after search in search form using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hey guys i am new in codeigniter and i am working on an application in which i have database and many records in database..i make a search form in which i make a text field in which user can fill any field value and search records.but here is a small problem..when i fill a name in textbox and click on search button no record display on view . . pls help me . . thanks ..

my controller is:

```
function search()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputsearch', 'Search Your Text Here','required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $search_this=$this->input->post('inputsearch');
        $this->load->model('mod_user');
        $searchmember=$this->mod_user->search_member($search_this);
        $data['searchmember'] = $searchmember;
        var_dump($searchmember);
        $this->load->view('view_home',$data);
        $this->load->view('view_homemember',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('ctl_home');
    }
}
```

view is:

```
<form class="userinfo" action="" method="post">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="15%;">Name</td>
                <td width="15%;">Moderator Name</td>
                <td width="20%;">KCC Branch</td>
                <td width="15%;">Father/Husband Name</td>
                <td width="15%;">Address</td>
                <td width="10%;">Date</td>
            </tr>
             <?php foreach ($rows as $row):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo anchor("Ctl_Home/edit_member/" . $row->member_id, 'Edit'); ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo site_url("ctl_dbcont/deleteinput/" . $row->member_id);?>" onclick="return confirm('Delete content?');">Delete</a></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->member_name;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->moderator_name;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->branch_name;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->father_name;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->address;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->date;  ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

my model is:

```
function search_member($search_this)
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT tbl_members.* , tbl_moderators.member_id AS moderator_id, tbl_moderators.member_name AS moderator_name, tbl_moderators.member_no AS moderator_no, tbl_branches.branch_name FROM tbl_members, tbl_members AS tbl_moderators, tbl_branches  WHERE tbl_members.moderator_id = tbl_moderators.member_id AND tbl_branches.branch_id = tbl_members.kcc_branch 
                                    AND  CONCAT(tbl_members.member_name, ' ', tbl_moderators.member_name, ' ',tbl_members.moderator_id, ' ', tbl_moderators.member_id, ' ',tbl_branches.branch_name, ' ',tbl_members.father_name, ' ',tbl_members.address, ' ',tbl_moderators.address, ' ',tbl_members.date, ' ',tbl_moderators.date)  like '%".$search_this."%'");
    if ($query->num_rows >= 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $data[]=$row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
}
```

Comment: and where is your model?

Comment: see edit . . my model @raheel shan

Comment: hey in your model this is wrong $query->num_rows >= 0 The number of rows must be 1 or more, so you want this: $query->num_rows >= 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should have been like this

```
<?php foreach ($searchmember as $row):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo anchor("Ctl_Home/edit_member/" . $row->member_id, 'Edit'); ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url("ctl_dbcont/deleteinput/" . $row->member_id);?>" onclick="return confirm('Delete content?');">Delete</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->member_name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->moderator_name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->branch_name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->father_name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->address;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->date;  ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It is $searchmember as $row  instead of $rows as $row in foreach

Comment: :- tnis is the view before search . . should i make another view for search result ..

Comment: :- i created another view for search esult and put code but nothing happen  `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/view_searchmoderator.php

Line Number: ` this error occur in all fields

Comment: you are not following the standard way of searchig. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374188/search-data-in-codeigniter/14374478#14374478) example

Comment: i got it thanx.  . .if any refrence link for sort and pagination of recods pls give me thanx again . .  @raheel shan

Comment: pagination on searching is not as straight forward as in simple pagination. Each time when you paginate you will need keeyword. Try putting the keyword in session and when you query while pagination check if keyword is available in session than create pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If $data['searchmember'] contains value in controller, 
you can access the varibale in view as $searchmember